# Infinite Loop in StreamReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have an application that's supposed to ask the user for an item number, search through a text file and then display the item with that item number. However, my program goes through an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise
{
class Inventory
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(@"SoldItems.txt",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);

        int count = 0;
        int num;
        string item;

        item = reader.ReadLine();
        while (item != null)
        {
            ++count;
            item = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        int size = (int)file.Length / count;

        Console.Write("Item Number? ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (num != 0)
        {
            file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            item = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        reader.Close();
        file.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The output looks like:

101 - Lamp, $100.00

102 - Rug, $5,000.00

Comment: `while(num != 0)` and where do you ever change `num` in that loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
Console.Write("Item Number? ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (num != 0)
{
    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    item = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The num never changes thus resulting in infinite loop. You should read the value in every repetition of the loop:

```
Console.Write("Item Number? ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (num != 0)
{
    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    item = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(item);

    Console.Write("Item Number? ");
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: I updated my code and it works, however the item # I enter doesn't match the correct item # in the text file. For example, if I enter the item numbers in order, they display correctly. But if I do random numbers, they don't correspond to the number I typed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like :

```
Console.Write("Item Number? ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (num != 0)
{
    // Do your seek operations here

    // run this again so you won't be stuck in the loop
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}        {
        file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        item = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```